# What could be causing a parser error in an Ironspeed website after moving to a new server?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, parsing, iis, ironspeed

I am trying to move old working ironspeed websites to new server,
they all worked correctly except for one which is showing parser error as below:

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'Smi:SITETableControl'.

Source Error:

```
Line 85: 
Line 86:                                        <ContentTemplate>
Line 87:                                    <Smi:SITETableControl runat="server" id="SITETableControl">
Line 88:                                                        
Line 89:     <!-- Begin Table Panel.html -->
```

what can be wrong, and what could be missing

I copied the file from the old server to the new after installing the same ASP.NET ver, oracle client ...

Comment: Could you please share in which server you have published it? Whats the version and have you checked the server error logs?

Comment: yes sure,new server is win server 19 64X, the old one is win 2012 R2 64x

Comment: No I didn't mean that, hosting server is in IIS or what? Which version? Did you checked the error log details?

Comment: IIS 7 on both servers and the log error is: Stack trace:    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseReader(StreamReader reader, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()

Comment: Are there anything in specified line ? Did you had the chance to set debug pointer on that line?